# How to display views on html5 video?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to get a sort of 'YouTube' like number of views section in my html. I want to add 1 everytime the viewer gets over minute 4 of the video.

So far I applied this Javascript but it does not look like working, what am I missing?

```
<section id="totViews">
<script>

document.getElementById("totViews").innerHTML = counter;

    var counter = 0;

    $('section video').on("timeupdate", function() {
        if ($('section video')[0].currentTime >= 4) { counter++;
        }
    });

    </script> views
    </section>
```

Comment: Firstly, you'll probably have to store that count serverside to make it persistent. Secondly, `currentTime` is in seconds, not minutes. Thirdly, you'll probably want to stop counting once the user is counted, otherwise your counter will keep on ticking for every second after 4 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript runs in the user's browser. It has no way of communicating with other browsers viewing the video, and it will stop counting when you close the page, so it will only ever be able to count how often you watched the video in the current session.

You need to load and store this information on your server somewhere if you want to make this work.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the information. Do you know where I can find more information about how to store information?

Comment: I'd just go to the library and pick up a book on the topic of building websites. There's a lot to learn.