# Video display in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning html, css, javascript for creating a simple website for learning purpose. I am able to display a video saved in my drive using video element in html page. I also want to display the title of the video, total length of the video, total views of the video in the same video. Please help me which part I need to concentrate more also where I can get information to learn these and able to display all the things I need in each video.

My html code:

```css
* {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}


body{
  margin: 0;
 }

header {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0px 6px 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
 display: inline;
 font-family: 'Oswald',sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 32px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul{
  display: inline;
 padding: 0px;
float: left;
}

nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type:none;
 color: white;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

nav ul li a{
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.homered{
 background-color: red;
 padding: 30px 10px 25px 10px;

}

.divider{
 background-color: red;
 height: 5px;

}

.homeblack:hover{
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 30px 10px 25px 10px;
}
div{
 width:250px;
 height:666px;
 background:#1A8DA9;
}
div a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 padding:20px;
 padding-right:100px
}
div ul li{
 list-style-type:none;
 display:block;
 padding :15px;

 border-bottom:1px solid #236D7F;
 }
 div ul li :hover{
  background:#4097AD;
  transition:linear all 0.40s;
  margin-left:10px;
 }
 div ul li a:hover{
  color:black;
 }



 #navBar {
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
  <title>Videos</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="videos.css">
  </head>


<body>
   <header>
  <nav>
  <h1> Main logo </h1>
   <ul id="nav"> 
    <li><a class="homeblack" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="homered" href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>

 </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <div id="navBar">

<ul>
 <li><a href="#">education videos </a></li>
 <li><a href="#">film videos</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">other videos </a></li>
</ul>

 </div>
<video title="abcd" controls width="250" height="160"> 
<source  src="videoplayback.mp4" />
</video> 
<video title="abcd" controls width="250" height="160"> 
<source src="videoplayback (1).mp4" />
</video> 

<video title="abcd" controls width="250" height="160"> 
<source src="1 Ton.mp4" /> 
</video> 





    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394106/6560716) helped you, remember you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the green check mark next to it.

Comment: the code for total length of the video is not working

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to keep track of views on the client-side (HTML, CSS, Javascript). Once a user leaves the page, that information is gone. You'll have to have some kind of back end to maintain that information (database, logging file, etc.)

As far as other metadata like the length of the video, that wouldn't be included in the native HTML5  tag. But you can just add that to the markup elsewhere.

Possible duplicate: [How to display views on html5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422024/how-to-display-views-on-html5-video)

Answer (score 1):

## What you want:

> ...to display the title of the video, total length of the video, total views of the video...

1. display the title of the video
2. video length
3. total views of the video

### 1:

If by "title of video", you mean filename, try this:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("video")).forEach(video=>{
    const title = (video.src || video.children[0].src).replace(/.*\//g, "").replace(/\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/, "").replace(/-|_/g, " ");
    video.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", title);
});
```

### 2:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("video")).forEach(video=>video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    const duration = videoPlayer.duration;
    video.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", Math.floor(video.duration / (60 * 60)) + ":" + Math.floor(video.duration / 60) + ":" + video.duration % 60)
}));
```

## 3:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44393993/6560716).

## DEMO:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("video")).forEach(video=>{
    const title = (video.src || video.children[0].src).replace(/.*\//g, "").replace(/\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/, "").replace(/-|_/g, " ");
    video.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", title);
});
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("video")).forEach(video=>video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    const duration = videoPlayer.duration;
    video.insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", Math.floor(video.duration / (60 * 60)) + ":" + Math.floor(video.duration / 60) + ":" + video.duration % 60)
}));
```

```css
* {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}


body{
  margin: 0;
 }

header {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0px 6px 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
 display: inline;
 font-family: 'Oswald',sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 32px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul{
  display: inline;
 padding: 0px;
float: left;
}

nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type:none;
 color: white;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

nav ul li a{
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.homered{
 background-color: red;
 padding: 30px 10px 25px 10px;

}

.divider{
 background-color: red;
 height: 5px;

}

.homeblack:hover{
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 30px 10px 25px 10px;
}
div{
 width:250px;
 height:666px;
 background:#1A8DA9;
}
div a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 padding:20px;
 padding-right:100px
}
div ul li{
 list-style-type:none;
 display:block;
 padding :15px;

 border-bottom:1px solid #236D7F;
 }
 div ul li :hover{
  background:#4097AD;
  transition:linear all 0.40s;
  margin-left:10px;
 }
 div ul li a:hover{
  color:black;
 }



 #navBar {
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
  <title>Videos</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="videos.css">
  </head>


<body>
   <header>
  <nav>
  <h1> Main logo </h1>
   <ul id="nav"> 
    <li><a class="homeblack" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="homered" href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>

 </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <div id="navBar">

<ul>
 <li><a href="#">education videos </a></li>
 <li><a href="#">film videos</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">other videos </a></li>
</ul>

 </div>
<video title="abcd" controls width="250" height="160"> 
<source  src="videoplayback.mp4" />
</video> 
<video title="abcd" controls width="250" height="160"> 
<source src="videoplayback (1).mp4" />
</video> 

<video title="abcd" controls width="250" height="160"> 
<source src="1 Ton.mp4" /> 
</video> 





    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi sir, i am a beginner in javascript able to write only simple codes using w3c tutorial, please suggest me which document i have to read to understand the code above.

Comment: @Haraharamahadev go to [here](https://output.jsbin.com/dodoqu), and right-click > save as and save the page.

Comment: the above link is taking to my own videos html page. I am looking for some document which helps me to understand the above code.